# Restructure using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data that comes to me within 1 long string (per row). Basically it’s semicolon delimited and the columns / answers are separated by an `=`. I'm trying to do the following:

Current structure:

```
 Row1: “Column1 = blah1;Column2 = blah2;Column3 = blah3;Column4 = blah4” 
 Row2: “Column1 = blah1;Column2 = blah2;Column3 = blah3;Column4 = blah4”
```

Convert to ->

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4
blah1|blah2|blah3|blah4
blah1|blah2|blah3|blah4
```

I believe the `tidyr` package within R is the way to go, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

This is as far as I've gotten using `tidyr`, but I am still getting errors:

```
# CREATE TEST DATA
mydata <- as.data.frame(c("Column1 = blah1; Column2 =  blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4","Column1 = blah1; Column2 =  blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4","Column1 = blah1; Column2 =  blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4"))
names(mydata) <- "TEST"

# Create dummy vector
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)

# Separate by ;
x <- separate(mydata, TEST, x, sep = ";" )
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Edited to fix formatting. When you paste code, you can select what you just pasted and then either hit `Ctrl+k` or click on the `{}` icon so that it is correctly formatted as code. Also, while it is good how you tried to make a reproducible example, it might help if you edit your question to 1) explain what the desired output for your test data is and 2) describe the errors that you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Will adjust for my next question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use [dplyr pipes](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) to show how to do this, step by step, printing the output after each step so you can see how the data structure evolves.

```
mydata <- as.data.frame(c("Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4","Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4","Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4")) 
names(mydata) <- "TEST"
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
> mydata
                                                                TEST
1 Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4
2 Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4
3 Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4
```

Here are the steps for transforming it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

1) separate by variable

```
mydata %>% 
separate(rows, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";")
```

output:

```
          Column1          Column2          Column3          Column4
1 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4
2 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4
3 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4
```

2) add row identifier

```
mydata %>% 
  separate(TEST, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(row=row.names(mydata))
```

output:

```
          Column1          Column2          Column3          Column4 row
1 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4   1
2 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4   2
3 Column1 = blah1  Column2 = blah2  Column3 = blah3  Column4 = blah4   3
```

3) reformat to long

```
mydata %>% 
  separate(TEST, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -row)
```

output:

```
   row     key            value
1    1 Column1  Column1 = blah1
2    2 Column1  Column1 = blah1
3    3 Column1  Column1 = blah1
4    1 Column2  Column2 = blah2
5    2 Column2  Column2 = blah2
6    3 Column2  Column2 = blah2
7    1 Column3  Column3 = blah3
8    2 Column3  Column3 = blah3
9    3 Column3  Column3 = blah3
10   1 Column4  Column4 = blah4
11   2 Column4  Column4 = blah4
12   3 Column4  Column4 = blah4
```

4) then extract data

```
mydata %>% 
  separate(TEST, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -row) %>% 
  extract(value, into="value", regex=".* = (.*)$")
```

output:

```
   row     key value
1    1 Column1 blah1
2    2 Column1 blah1
3    3 Column1 blah1
4    1 Column2 blah2
5    2 Column2 blah2
6    3 Column2 blah2
7    1 Column3 blah3
8    2 Column3 blah3
9    3 Column3 blah3
10   1 Column4 blah4
11   2 Column4 blah4
12   3 Column4 blah4
```

5) spread it back out into wide format, if desired

```
mydata %>% 
  separate(TEST, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -row) %>% 
  extract(value, into="value", regex=".* = (.*)$") %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

output:

```
  row Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1   1   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
2   2   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
3   3   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
```

6) drop the row identifier, if desired

```
mydata %>% 
  separate(TEST, into=paste0("Column", 1:4), sep=";") %>% 
  mutate(row=row.names(mydata)) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -row) %>% 
  extract(value, into="value", regex=".* = (.*)$") %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

output:

```
  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
1   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
2   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
3   blah1   blah2   blah3   blah4
```

Comment: Very much appriciate the detail, helps me learn! Unfortunately I'm getting an error when trying to run code under step 1) Error in matrix(unlist(pieces), ncol = n, byrow = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Comment: Any idea what I could use to fix this? Seems as though it doesn't like the column name?

Comment: Do you get that error when you use the test data from the question (what I used in my answer)? If so, then it's an issue with the separate function --- probably you have another library loaded that has a separate function that's interfering with tidyr's separate. You can fixe that by writing `tidyr::separate(` instead of just `separate(`. If you're NOT getting that error on the test data but you are on your own data, then it's an issue with your data. Explore your data with functions like `str`, `View` and `summary` to make sure that it all looks correct to you.

Comment: Also note that the data you send into `separate` via the pipe needs to be a data.frame. It can't be a list, matrix, etc. You can see what class your data object is (among other things) with `str`

Comment: I've checked all your recommendations and everything seems to check out. I verified that mydata is a data.frame and also the column (TEST) is a type character. Also just to make sure I added in tidyr::separate. Here is my latest version of the code: mydata %>% 
  tidyr::separate(as.data.frame(rows, into=paste0("column", 1:4)), sep=";")

Comment: Now the only message I'm getting is "Error: Invalid column specification"

Comment: The use of pipes means you *don't* also include the dataframe in the separate command --- the output of the last command (mydata) gets used as the first argument in the next command. Use either `mydata %>% tidyr::separate(TEST, into=paste0("column", 1:4), sep=";")` or `tidyr::separate(mydata, TEST, into=paste0("column", 1:4), sep=";")`

Comment: That was it! I swear I knew that, just didn't see it. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base r attempt

```
#Example data provided
data <- data.frame(
 string=c(
  "Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4",
  "Column1 = blah1; Column2 = blah2; Column3 = blah3; Column4 = blah4"))

#Modulo function for odd and even numbers
odd <- function(x) x%%2 != 0 
even <- function(x) x%%2 == 0 

#split string based on condition and remove all xtra whitespace
s <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$string), '= |;')))

#bind the data into a df no factors
data <- data.frame(rbind(unique(s[even(1:length(s))]),
                   unique(s[even(1:length(s))])),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
#rename column names exctrating the odd vector numbers from s
colnames(data) <- unique(s[odd(1:length(s))])

data
```

Comment: np! you could probably wrap it in a function and use `mutate` for tidyr. maybe in spirit of something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579056/dplyr-split-string-into-a-comma-separated-list